# Sms Listener doesnt respond

Tags: android

I am doing the following code in order to listen for incoming SMS's
and it doesn't work, I never reach to the reciever class.

**I am Using i1 (Android 1.5)**

some code:

```
  Manifest.xml:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

and this is the broadcaster class:

```
        public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
{

    Log.d("SmsReceiver", "I GOT THE SMS");

}
```

}

After I send sms to my phone, the line above never printed on the Logcat.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed the permissions outside the /application tag

Answer (score 1):

Where are you registering the receiver?  `You need to call registerReceiver(yourReceiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED).`